# Falha ao obter um arquivo .txt para download

Tags: c#

Tenho um método onde após uma consulta, crio um arquivo .txt salvando alguns parâmetros. Minha necessidade é obter esse .txt, onde vou tratar esse arquivo em um JavaScript (angularJs) para efetuar o download.

Mas ao tentar obter esse arquivo, tenho um retorno com o erro:

> exceptionMessage: "O processo não pode acessar o arquivo 'E:\Projetos\nfs-e\Api\TEXT\users.txt' porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo."

Back end onde crio e salvo o arquivo .txt:

```
public HttpResponseMessage ObterNotas(UsuarioDTO user)
{
    var dataInicial = user.CompetenciaInicial;
    var dataFinal = user.CompetenciaFinal;

    var listaNotas = this.DbContext.ObterNotasRepo(dataInicial, dataFinal);

    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString());

    string new_dir = path + "/TEXT/"+ "users.txt";

    HttpResponseMessage response = null;

    if (!File.Exists(new_dir))
    {
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
    }

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    List<string> lista = new List<string>();
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new_dir))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listaNotas.Count ; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                writer.Write(listaNotas[i].Usuario.CpfCnpj.ToString() + '|' + listaNotas[i].Usuario.RazaoSocial.ToString() + "\r\n");
            }
           writer.Write(listaNotas[i].NumeroRegistro.ToString() + "\r\n");
        }
        writer.Flush();

        response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(new_dir);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = new_dir;

    }
    return response;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.obterUsuario = function () 
{
    $scope.search.prestadorId = authService.authentication.user.codigo;
    userService.getUser($scope.search).then(function (result) {
      if (result.data.length > 0) {
        var data = result.data
        console.log(typeof (data));

        var headers = result.headers;
        headers = headers();

        var timeInMs = Date.now();

        var contentType = headers['content-type'];

        var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
        try {
          var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
          var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

          linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
          linkElement.setAttribute("download", "teste" + '-' + timeInMs + ".txt");

          var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click",
            {
              "view": window,
              "bubbles": true,
              "cancelable": false
            });
          linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        } catch (ex) {
          console.log(ex);
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ao que parece é o que a mensagem informa que o arquivo está sendo usado por algum outro processo, veja se você não esqueceu ele aberto em outro programa, VS, Notepad e talvez até algum anti-virus

Comment: `ms.Close();`, mas não entendi nem pra que o `MemoryStream`...

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, ele n está aberto em nenhum programa

Comment: Por que não usa `File.AppendAllText`? Pelo código, me parece que você tem um background com Java.

Comment: Em que linha ocorre o erro?

Comment: Coloque o código relativo ao objeto `response` fora do `using`. O ficheiro só é corretamente fechado depois de ser feito o `Dispose` do objeto (que faz também o `Close()` do `StreamWriter`).

Comment: Alias, qual é o objetivo de persistir em um arquivo de texto o conteúdo que está no banco de dados, como você vai tratar a concorrência de IO desse arquivo em processos "simultâneos"? Outro ponto, um txt com o mimetype de pdf, não será um arquivo pdf válido

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, só preciso obter esse arquivo .txt salvo na pasta definida. Quanto ao objetivo, são por outras razões que preciso persistir em um arquivo.

Comment: Vou retornar o total que obtive na consulta em forma de .txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom a sua prática não faz muito sentido e a persistência do conteúdo em um arquivo de texto antes da resposta, que será sobrescrito a cada execução e  só serve para lhe trazer problemas de concorrência.

Além do teste para ver se o arquivo existe, você não está lendo ele em nenhum outro lugar e no final você está retornando um arquivo txt como se fosse um pdf, o que só vai gerar um arquivo inválido.

Segue o seu código com uns pequenos ajustes, apenas para evitar algumas exceptions e segregar minimante as operações de escrita e leitura, que não deveriam estar nem no mesmo método. Mas realmente sugiro que você reavalie a sua solução.

```
public HttpResponseMessage ObterNotas(UsuarioDTO user)
{
    var dataInicial = user.CompetenciaInicial;
    var dataFinal = user.CompetenciaFinal;

    var listaNotas = this.DbContext.ObterNotasRepo(dataInicial, dataFinal);

    string path =  Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString());

    string new_dir = path + "/TEXT/" + "users.txt";

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();


    if (!File.Exists(new_dir))
    {
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);

    }


    List<string> lista = new List<string>();
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new_dir))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listaNotas.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                writer.Write(listaNotas[i].Usuario.CpfCnpj.ToString() + '|' + listaNotas[i].Usuario.RazaoSocial.ToString() + "\r\n");
            }
            writer.Write(listaNotas[i].NumeroRegistro.ToString() + "\r\n");
        }
        writer.Flush();

    }

    var content = File.ReadAllBytes(new_dir);
    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(content );
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/text");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = new_dir;

    return response;
}
```